# Unknown column in field list PHP MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to perform this query:

```
$result = "INSERT INTO `user`(`username`, `ip`, `country`) VALUES ('$username','$location[ip]','$location[country]')";

@mysql_query($result) or die("Error:". mysql_error());
```

Tried ever combination of single and double quotes, but constantly getting error:

```
Error:Unknown column 'ip' in 'field list'
```

Column 'ip' does exist in database, when I echo out query and run it in PHPMyAdmin it works perfectly

```
INSERT INTO `user`(`username`, `ip`, `country`) VALUES ('name32','127.0.0.1','mycountry')
```

Comment: post the table structure

Comment: Print out the sql the is being generated, that will give you an idea if your query is correct.

Comment: Most likley, there's no `ip` field in the `user` table.

Comment: how can I run echoed query in PHPMyAdmin then?

Comment: What if you do 
`mysql_query("INTO `user`(`username`, `ip`, `country`) VALUES ('name32','127.0.0.1','mycountry')") or die(mysql_error() );`
does that work?

Comment: Martijn, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Comment: Did you copy the backtick at the end? You shouldn't :P I tried to highlight it as code, but it seams to break. I ment to suggest you copy the echoëd query (which works in the database) direxctly into thew mysql_query() function.

Comment: None of your column names are reserved words so no need for back tics around their names, same for the table name. However that should not prevent your query running. Can I suggest you echo out the query along with the error message in the die statement?

Answer (score 1):

im thinking that you might have made a typo in the database? I use IP every once in a while and im never having any problems. Could it be you named the column  IP (uppercased)? That might break things

To make sure the name is correct, you could change the name to 'something' and change the query. If it starts working, its something in the names-area, otherwise you know for sure its not that

Comment: When I swap 'ip' with 'country', than country makes an error. I don't understand why echoing result out and manually running query makes no error

Comment: check database connections once

Comment: Yep, different DB was selected, containing same table but different columns. Such a stupid mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Change your SQL query like this

```
$result = "INSERT INTO `user` (`username`, `ip`, `country`) VALUES ('".$username."','".$location['ip']."','".$location['country']."')";
```

Comment: @user2411147 Try this. Is that work `@mysql_query("INSERT INTO user (username, ip, country) VALUES ('name32','127.0.0.1','mycountry')") or die("Error:". mysql_error());` Or you still get the same error??